# Aggregate data via d3 to form y axis and y values

Tags: d3.js

I had to reformat this JSON file from what I originally had and am having a hard time creating a summary graph with it. I have the x axis working the way I want but am not having the same luck with the y axis and y values. I need a total of all open, all responded, etc.

```
    y.domain([0, d3.max(color.domain(), function (d) { return d; })]);
```

and this is the part that plots the rectangles, as I mentioned, the x is correct, just the y needs some TLC.

```
    svg.selectAll(".bar")
            .data(color.domain())
          .enter().append("rect")
            .attr("class", "bar")
            .style("fill", color)
            //.attr("height", function (d) { return height - y(d.stati) })
            .attr("x", function (d) { return x(d); })
            .attr("width", 60);
```

here is a jsfiddle with a link to an example data set:
http://jsfiddle.net/ba5m8/

dataset:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/23726217/queryStatusBar.json

Comment: Are you looking for something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ba5m8/1/)?

Comment: You might also find [this answer helpful](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21563181/3128209), since you seem to have gotten lost by the (rather confusing) code using the color scale domain as a list of categories.  It's not an approach that I would ever use in a tutorial.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff yes! except the y axis should be a total instead of a percent but I think I can figure that part out - thank you so much!!